# Roslyn Check If Field Declaration has been assigned to

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm writing an app which converts keys to use resources from a RESX File.  This code was working with local variables before:

```
public static void AnalyzeConstDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var fieldDeclaration = (FieldDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;

    if (false == IsValidFieldDeclaration(context, fieldDeclaration))
    {
        return;
    }

    var firstVariable = fieldDeclaration.Declaration.Variables.FirstOrDefault();
    var dataFlowAnalysis = context.SemanticModel.AnalyzeDataFlow(firstVariable);

    var variableSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(firstVariable);
    if (dataFlowAnalysis.WrittenOutside.Contains(variableSymbol))
    {
        return;
    }


    var firstSymbol = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(firstVariable);

    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, context.Node.GetLocation(), firstSymbol.Name));
}
```

However when I try to get the dataFlowAnalysis I receive an error:

> Additional information: statementOrExpression is not a StatementSyntax or an ExpressionSyntax.

How can Ideally just need to see if anyone has written to this variable outside of the declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DataFlow works by analyzing order of execution within a single method.
It doesn't make sense for class-level fields.

Instead, you should use a simple syntax visitor (or `SymbolFinder`) to search the entire class for assignments to the field.

You'll probably also want to check whether it's ever passed as a `ref` parameter.